# "you have bought" vs "you bought"

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

*The Dark Knight (2008)*

> "Oh, and by the way, the suit? It wasn't cheap. You ought to know, **you
> bought it**."

This is Joker's phrase and could he say "you have bought it" in this case?

Comment: He could not _have said_ "You have bought it". I haven't seen the film, but I assume the person being addressed had not bought the suit recently, if he had to be reminded of the price.

Comment: Why even suggest that? What is the problem with the simple past?

Comment: This is from Swan's Practical English Usage: "we prefer a past tense when we identify the person responsible for a present situation".

Answer (score 1):

It just doesn't make any particular sense to say *you have bought it*.

Buying the suit is one specific and completed event that happened at one time in the past, so the simple past is the most natural tense to use.

Using the present perfect indicates some kind of action that began in the past and continues to the present.  For example, you could say "I *have bought* many suits in the past" because the process of buying suits is not necessarily over; I could buy more suits today or in the future.  If somebody said to me, "You have bought the suit", I would think "...and what?" because it implies some kind of ongoing process.

Answer (score 1):

It's often subjective, but it depends on the context and emphasis of why you mention something. In particular, whether you focus on the event of origin, or on current state of affairs, caused by that past event.

> "You could wear that suit to the party tonight. You have bought it and you have spent a lot of money on it, you could as well make use of it."

This focuses on the fact you have this suit currently available for your use and that you don't have the money which you used up to buy it. Not wearing the suit is just wasteful - now, currently.

> "Oh, and by the way, the suit? It wasn't cheap. You ought to know, you bought it."

could be rewritten as:

> "Oh, and by the way, the suit? It wasn't cheap. You have known that since the day you bought it."

The focus is the knowledge about the price of the suit, which you possess now. You obtained that knowledge when paying for the suit. The suit itself - where is it, what happened to it - isn't as relevant. Your knowledge of the price paid for it is what's in focus, and the event that gave you that knowledge is long in the past.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. There is one of the use cases present perfect : "We use the present perfect to talk about past actions or events when time is not mentioned, i.e. we don’t say when these events happened.", and i'm little confused because of this.

Comment: @mistake22 One important thing people miss about present perfect: It's a **present tense**, despite outer appearance of a **past tense**. You talk about this moment, you focus on the present situation, the past event is just a reference, a hook, an explanation of how you landed in the current state. "I have bought a suit" has much more in common with "I have a suit" than with "I bought a suit". This tense is pretty rare in other languages, as it's totally a regular present tense but with extra paint of the past thrown on it. "I have a suit which I bought" is something much easier to translate.