Past simple and present perfect interchangeably
I want to know that I can speak past action by using present perfect. A week ago, it was my birthday and I bought a car.Now my friend comes to my house and sees the car.He asks that have you bought a car? I answer yes,

I bought that car a week ago on my birthday.

Or

I have bought that car on my birthday.

I understand that 1 is simple and fine to answer but I want to know that can I use 2 with present perfect because present perfect related with  past and present.
Can I use 2 to talk the past action because I want to more understand present perfect.

#1 should be I bought that car a week ago on my birthday. #2 is invalid. Don't use Present Perfect unless you know you need it (which you very rarely do). Your friend can use Present Perfect "Have you bought a car?" because he can see an unfamiliar car outside your house (so the answer to his question is relevant to what he's probably looking at right now). But he didn't have to. He could use "do-support" and just ask "Did you buy a new car?".

Never use the present perfect with ago. ago=simple past.

Hello sir according to explanation ""You could wear that suit to the party tonight. You have bought it and you have spent a lot of money on it, you could as well make use of it." In this explanation someone bought suit and spent a lot of money but dont wear so he is reminded of.What I understand that all present perfect tenses expressed are past events and relate to now. Why in this explanation can use present perfect? @FumbleFingers

https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/303853/you-have-bought-vs-you-bought. @FumbleFingers

To repeat: Don't use Present Perfect unless you know you need it (which you very rarely do). For your "suit" example, just go with You bought it and you spent a lot of money on it... and forget about the Perfect. It's clear from your original "birthday car" example that you have much to learn about English. Ignore Perfect verb forms for as long as possible - you'll make far more mistakes by using the Perfect when you shouldn't, rather than by failing to use it when you should.

Thanks a lot sir@FumbleFingers
